# Dell Latitude 5490 not coming back from sleep mode

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics

there is a known issue on the Dell Latitude 5490 model (with a driver update only for Windows):
https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=GG5FR

This issue related to screen turn off and not light back when coming back from sleep.

According to the windows workaround suggested before the drivers update, the suggestion was to "DISPLAY TURN OFF set to NEVER" on windows which solved the issue.

How can I accomplish the same in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with Gnome 3.28.2?

Another possibility is that if someone have the same model with Ubuntu and solved the issue with other method it will be good to hear.

- I have tried to install some random Power Manager apps with additional features but with no use - the built in power management is pretty limited in options.

Thanks.

Comment: I had, I believe, the same issue with the same laptop. Now I use the "unblank lock screen" extension to prevent the laptop from turning off the screen. It works fine.

Comment: Apparently that extension is found here for anyone else looking for it: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1414/unblank/